# How can I get "Copy output" to get copied to output of an assembly using the library?

Tags: msbuild, mono, monodevelop

So in the least clear question title ever, what I'm trying to describe is a situation like so:

- Project A, with files that have "Copy output" set to "Only if newer" (or "Always", it doesn't matter in this case).
- Project B which has Project A as a dependency.

The files marked as "Copy output" only get copied to Project A's output directory, but I also want them to be copied to Project B, since Project B relies on them.

Is there any way to do this while maintaining MonoDevelop compatibility? (MonoDevelop does not use MSBuild or Mono's equivalent for doing actual builds, so any solution has to be one that doesn't use custom MSBuild steps)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with Mono.  Do "Post Build Events" work there?

In the properties of ProjectA, go to properties.
Go to "Build Events"

Add this event:

```
copy $(TargetDir)ProjectAAssemblyName.dll $(ProjectDir)..\ProjectBThirdPartyReferences\ProjectAAssemblyName.dll
```

Then inside of ProjectB, reference \ProjectBThirdPartyReferences\ProjectAAssemblyName.dll

You may have to tweak the paths a bit.

My advise is to NOT copy ProjectAAssemblyName.dll to the \bin\ folder of ProjectB.

.........

Comment: The problem with post build events is that they are inherently not cross-platform, which kind of defeats the point of using MonoDevelop.